# Set private network ip in vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I'm trying to use vagrant with Windows as guest.
When I use config.vm.network to configure a host only network with static ip, the setting won't work.
Here is my Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "win08r2"
  config.vm.guest = :windows
  config.ssh.max_tries = 1
  config.ssh.timeout = 10
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.gui = true
  end
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip :"192.168.56.10"
  config.vm.network :public_network
end
```

The ip of vm is something like 196.254.xx.xx or other, just not same with 192.168.56.10.

Is there any problems with my vagrantfile?

Thanks,

Comment: According to [the vagrant doc](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html) everything seems write - may be a problem with windows guests in general... may be you should open an issue at vagrant and ask there.

Answer (score 8):

I could not get my CentOS vm to take an ip using vagrant's private network. It made a new interface with that ip, but wasn't using it. I ended up doing

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "3072", "--cpus", "2", "--natnet1", "10.252/16"]
end
```

Along with allocating some resources, this line will force virtualbox to use nat with 10.252.**xx**.yy. The default ip for the first interface is 10.252.**0**.15. Each interface after increases **xx** by two. yy stays at 15. That is the behavior of virtualbox, not vagrant. Hopefully that helps somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

This setup works for me:

`config.vm.network "hostonly", "192.168.56.10"`

If you want to access your host machine, you host machine ip address would be `192.168.56.1`

Comment: Thanks, but this syntax works with previous version of Vagrantfile. https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1628

Comment: I second that, this does not work with Vagrant version 1.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable DHCP, for that network host if you're using VirtualBox underneath.

e.g. If your network interface is `vboxnet0`, open VirtualBox, Navigate to `File > Preferences > Network` and click on the `Host-only Networks` tab.

Then edit your network interface by clicking on the edit button after choosing `vboxnet0`. 
Once the edit dialog box opens, navigate to the `DHCP Server` tab and un-check `Enable DHCP` option.

This way the network interface will not be assigned an IP automatically.